# bracket order binance futures api

Tags: api, cryptocurrency, binance

I am creating an application for fun that calls into the binance API. Basically what i would like to do is to create a bracket order (with two legs for take profit and for stop loss), at a certain price (limit order). I am curious whether that is possible to do so for futures? I have not seen info in connection with this in their documentation.
Is the best thing I can do to put 3 orders at the same time, with 1 limit order for the entry, 1 stop order for the stop loss and 1 limit order for take profit? That makes the whole thing rather complicated because I always have to check whether my entry order is 100% filled otherwise, my stop loss or take profit order would keep me in the market in the other direction...

Any input regarding this?